# EF Entity with TimeSpan property not supported in Breeze.js?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, breeze

I am getting a NotSupportedException after I added a TimeSpan property to the Employee entity in the DocCode project. So I know it isn't supported but... Are there plans to do a conversion or a way to get past this. We use TimeSpan extensively in our entities, is there a way to support TimeSpan or plans to?

1. Added Duration property

> ```
> public class Employee
> {
>     ...
>     public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
>
>     public TimeSpan? Duration { get; set; }
>
>     [MaxLength(60)]
>     public string Address { get; set; }
>     ...
> }
> ```

When the MetaData() method is called on the NorthwindController running the unit test it fails:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233067
Message=There is no store type corresponding to the EDM type 'Edm.Time(Nullable=True)' of primitive type 'Time'.
Source=System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderManifest.GetStoreType(TypeUsage edmType)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.StructuralTypeMappingGenerator.MapTableColumn(EdmProperty property, DbTableColumnMetadata tableColumnMetadata, Boolean isInstancePropertyOnDerivedType, Boolean isKeyProperty)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.PropertyMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmEntityType entityType, IEnumerable`1 properties, DbEntitySetMapping entitySetMapping, DbEntityTypeMappingFragment entityTypeMappingFragment, IList`1 propertyPath, Boolean createNewColumn)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.EntityTypeMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmEntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(EdmModel model, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.GenerateDatabaseMapping(EdmModel model, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
   at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.GetCsdlFromObjectContext(Object context)
   at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.GetCsdlFromDbContext(Object context)
   at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.BuildJsonMetadata()
   at Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider.Metadata()
   at DocCode.Controllers.NorthwindController.Metadata() in c:\Users\anwalker\Downloads\breeze-runtime-plus-0.78.2\Samples\DocCode\DocCode\Controllers\NorthwindController.cs:line 20
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a little research, it makes sense to serialize a .NET timespan to the javascript client using the ISO8601 'duration' standard which would represent a timespan in days, hours, minutes, and seconds as a formatted string something like: "PnnnDTnnHnnMnn.nnnS". Obviously, you will need a javascript library on the client to interpret and work with this.  Would this meet your needs?

I've added this to our feature request log, but please also add it to the Breeze [User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions) (and vote for it :)).  This helps us prioritize the outstanding feature requests.

Comment: Moment.js works natively with ISO8601 durations.  And IMNSHO everyone should be using Moment.js when working with dates in Javascript anyway.

Answer (score 2):

TimeSpan support was added in build 0.84.1.

TimeSpans are represented as ISO 8601 'duration' strings on the breeze client. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Full query support includes the ability to both filter and return TimeSpan/Duration properties. i.e.

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Contracts").where("TimeElapsed", ">", "PT4H30M");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm..  The request makes sense.  But what would you want it converted to in javascript, a string or a number of seconds since a point in time or ....  Is there a standard javascript representation for a .NET timespan?

Comment: Hi @JayTraband:  Can you elaborate on how you solved this please? I have a TimeSpan .NET service returning time fields as "PT12H" via Breeze which seems to be a standard convention. What do I do with it in Javascript to convert it to a field like "10:00"?

Comment: I would use moment.js for this.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157341/how-can-i-humanize-this-complete-duration-in-moment-js-javascript