# How can I humanize this complete duration in moment.js / javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a 'time remaining' counter in place for file uploads.  The remaining duration is calculated and converted into milliseconds like so:

```
var elapsedTime = e.timeStamp - timestarted;
var speed = e.loaded / elapsedTime;
var estimatedTotalTime = e.totalSize / speed;
var timeLeftInSeconds = (estimatedTotalTime - elapsedTime) / 1000;
```

I then build an array which I intend to build into a humanized string.  The array is as follows:

```
var time = {
              years : Math.round(moment.duration(timeLeftInSeconds, 'milliseconds').years()),
              months : Math.round(moment.duration(timeLeftInSeconds, 'milliseconds').months()),
              days : Math.round(moment.duration(timeLeftInSeconds, 'milliseconds').days()),
              hours : Math.round(moment.duration(timeLeftInSeconds, 'milliseconds').hours()),
              minutes : Math.round(moment.duration(timeLeftInSeconds, 'milliseconds').minutes()),
              seconds : Math.round(moment.duration(timeLeftInSeconds, 'milliseconds').seconds())
};
```

This all works perfectly and if I output a string representation of this data like so:

```
  console.log(time.years + ' years, ' + time.months + ' months, ' + time.days + ' days, ' + time.hours + ' hours, '+ time.minutes + ' minutes, ' + time.seconds + ' seconds');
```

I it returns a nice simple stream of remaining time like so:

```
0 years, 0 months, 0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes, 7 seconds
```

What I now need to do is humanize this output so that the string is built dependent on the time remaining. e.g

- 2 years and 3 months remaining
- 1 hour, 32 minutes and 41 seconds remaining
- 7 seconds remaining
- 3 minutes 46 seconds remaining
- 6 seconds remaining

etc...etc...

Now I know that moment.js has the abiility to automatically humanize durations which works fine for single values but this can have multiple possible values ( hours/minutes/seconds etc)

How can I go about humanizing this data either with moment.js or by manually building the string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your best bet would be something like this:

```
function humanize(time){
    if(time.years   > 0){   return time.years   + ' years and '     + time.months   + ' months remaining';}
    if(time.months  > 0){   return time.months  + ' months and '    + time.days     + ' days remaining';}
    if(time.days    > 0){   return time.days    + ' days and '      + time.hours    + ' hours remaining';}
    if(time.hours   > 0){   return time.hours   + ' hours and '     + time.minutes  + ' minutes and ' + time.seconds + ' seconds remaining';}
    if(time.minutes > 0){   return time.minutes + ' minutes and '   + time.seconds  + ' seconds remaining';}
    if(time.seconds > 0){   return time.seconds + ' seconds remaining';}
    return "Time's up!";
}
```

Alternatively, you could use this function:

```
function humanize(time){
    var o = '';
    for(key in time){
        if(time[key] > 0){
            if(o === ''){
                o += time[key] + ' ' + key + ' ';
            }else{
                return o + 'and ' + time[key] + ' ' + key + ' remaining';
            }
        }
    }
    return o + 'remaining';
}
```

It returns `"x <time> and y <time> remaining"`, for the 2 greatest values. (Or only seconds in the last case.

Comment: Thanks Cerberus, I thought of doing something similar (although in a loop through the array) but if the duration is large for instance 2 years I would like to only return the years, yet for smaller durations I would like to return several (3 mins and 42 seconds).  I was hoping moment.js already handled this but I guess not.

Comment: @gordyr: No problem at all :D

Comment: Sorry Cerbrus, I just realised that the function I ended up using was actually posted by user1933818 before you edited it into your answer.  I feel it's only fair that he gets the credit for the correct answer.  Hope you understand mate.  Cheers!

Comment: @gordyr: WHAT? I wrote that thing myself! He posted that at `13:02:59`. I last edited my code at `12:56:25`. That guy blatantly copied that half of my answer. He posted that after I last edited it.

Comment: @gordyr: The other answer was removed.

Comment: How strange... On my end it appeared that he had written it earlier... Sorry about that mate! First time I've seen that on SO!! Hopefully all sorted now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

My [HumanizeDuration.js](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js) library sounds like exactly what you want:

```
humanizeDuration(1);         // "1 millisecond"
humanizeDuration(3000);      // "3 seconds"
humanizeDuration(2012);      // "2 seconds, 12 milliseconds"
humanizeDuration(97320000);  // "1 day, 3 hours, 2 minutes"
```

Looks like my answer's a bit late, but maybe it'll help others looking at this question!

Answer (score 4):

You should give a try on this plugin: [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)

Its syntax is very convenient:

```
var moment = require('moment');
require("moment-duration-format");
moment.duration(32832, "seconds").format("h [hrs]: m [min]: s [sec]")
// => 9 hrs: 7 min: 12 sec"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being happy with date-fns' [formatDistanceToNow](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/formatDistanceToNow). You can add that function without having to add the whole library like moment.js