# How to use moment js to convert "hh:mm:ss" time format into hours, minutes, seconds?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-conversion

For example, I have a time string in the form "00:30:00", so the output should be 30 minutes. Or if we have "15:00:30", so the output should be 15 hours 30 seconds.
Can it be done using moment? or do I need to write my own code?

Comment: If question is just about *Can it be done using moment?* **Yes.**

Comment: No it's not just about that. I want to know how?

Comment: @timster ... I haven't tried anything yet. I think the question is pretty clear though. Moment helps to convert datetime formats and I want to convert this "hh:mm:ss" into this "hh hours mm minutes ss seconds".

Comment: @AyushGoswami, just trying to help you understand what is expected of a question here on SO. (It's more than you've provided.) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I humanize this complete duration in moment.js / javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157341/how-can-i-humanize-this-complete-duration-in-moment-js-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a post that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21840646/4573534

All you need to do now is to parse `hh:mm:ss` to milliseconds