# Difference time from current date to minutes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm looking for a way to get something like: 10 minutes after taking the difference from a `Date.now()` - a date already passed.

Like this:

```
const test: any = new DeviceModel({...device})
const difference = new Date().getTime() - test.accessTime
const accesed_at = expect : 10 minutes.
```

But I'm not thinking how can I do with my difference time for minutes that have already passed the date.

Comment: The difference will be in milliseconds, do the math.

Comment: If that's about formatting duration in miliseconds into some human-readable form, you may find of use [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62590689/11299053). Pay attention, though, it is ***seconds***-based, so you would need to adjust slightly.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question itself, but `new Date().getTime()` could be simplified to `Date.now()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const differenceInMilliSeconds = new Date().getTime() - test.accessTime; //difference in milli-seconds
const difference = differenceInMilliSeconds /(1000 * 60);
```

Code assume that `test.accessTime` is *the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch*

Comment: Where UNIX epoch === ECMAScript epoch. ;-)